# MYSQL - Query Certain String's Length

Tags: mysql

For example I have a table column : `lorem,ipsum,mini,momo,testing`

I need to select total 'Comma' 's  count.

Is it possible to query it as result of : `4` because having 4 comma in the column ?

Does mysql have any trick like select character length by filtering certain words like :
`SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(section,',') FROM table WHERE 1 = 1` ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#c10495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  Just use subtraction:

```
select length(section) - length(replace(section, ',', ''))
```

However, you shouldn't be storing lists of things in strings.  Instead, use a junction table with one row per item.